# FireFox showing css files in Style Editor but not in Network Monitor

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools, network-monitoring

I have CSS files that are being loaded correctly in FireFox (52.0.1). They are listed in the Style Editor tab, but not in the Network Monitor tab. It doesn't matter if I click All or CSS in the Network Monitor tab, no CSS files show up.

I am including the css files in the `<head>` like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://{path}/css/print.css" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://{path}/plugins/components/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css" media="all">
```

[image: CSS files not showing up in Network Monitor tab with "All" selected.]

[image: CSS files not showing up in Network Monitor tab with "CSS" selected.]

[image: CSS files showing up in the Style Editor tab.]

I'm assuming they're supposed to show up in the Network Monitor tab considering there is a CSS option, so what gives?

Comment: get firebug on Firefox, you can step in in the net tab see the exactly whats being loaded or not

Comment: @UlugToprak firebug does show the css files. Thanks. Any idea why the FireFox dev tools don't?

Comment: Note that [Firebug is discontinued and breaks once multi-process Firefox is enabled](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/). @GreeKatrina In your first screenshot you sorted the requests by type. Could it be that you simply have to scroll down? I assume the CSS files are served under a different MIME type and therefore don't appear when you set the *CSS* filter.

Comment: @SebastianZartner Good thought, but no, they don't appear below (or above). All it shows are js files and images.

Comment: FWIW the screenshot says 15 requests but only shows 8.

Comment: In any case all I can suggest is either trying Nightly (to see if it is still a bug); or filing a bug so it can be investigated.

Comment: @TomTromey Though the list of CSS files also shows 8 files and the scrollbar indicates that there are much more, so there must have been more than 15 requests.

Comment: @TomTromey What is Nightly? I didn't include all of the files for security reasons. Sebastian is right in his assumption of more than 15 requests. The css files show up in Firebug's Network tab, so I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your screenshot says that there were only 15 requests but you obviously have 8 files in the Network Monitor and an even larger number of CSS files, this looks like a bug in the Firefox DevTools.

I suggest you first [try out a new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). If it works there, its obviously a bug in your profile. You may track it further down to a specific preference or add-on causing the CSS files not to be listed within the Network Monitor, but in any case you should [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Netmonitor).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't include the whole list of files for security reasons. I figured people would see that the files didn't add up. I didn't know about the profile thing though, that's really handy. It seems like a bit of a process, so I'll try it out when I can. If it does end up being a bug I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I used [Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/#nightly) as suggested in the question's comments and the CSS files show up in the Network tab, so it must be a bug they are actively fixing.